# Facebook like button count on web page doesn´t correspond to Facebook insights number

Tags: facebook-insights

I have an issue with the like button count on a webpage beeing much higher than the count reported in Facebook Insights for that same page on my domain.

For example when I look at an article that has been published for two days the button on site reports 18 likes. If i select the same timespan for that article in Facebook insights it reports 4 likes and 2 shares.

How can the numbers differ so much?

Thank´s for any advice!

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem, just Googled and found this post: http://faso.com/fineartviews/21028/facebook-like-button-count-inaccuracies. It explains very in details why and how.